# Parse json array string using jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I have this JSON:

```
[{"header": "test" , "test2" : "test2"}]
```

I'm trying to parse this using [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp).

Here's my code snippet:

```
 Json::CharReaderBuilder builder;
 Json::CharReader *reader = builder.newCharReader();
 Json::Value root;
 bool parseRet = reader->parse(serverResponse.c_str(),serverResponse.c_str() +serverResponse.size(), &root, &errors);
```

`parseRet` returns `true`. But `root` does not include json data.

How do I parse this?

Comment: Did you check the `errors`?

Comment: @Azeem Yes, errors is empty string.

Comment: try without [] paranthesis?

Comment: @anas: Can you add your full code example with the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

> `parseRet` returns `true`. But `root` does not include JSON data.

This sounds like an issue with the way you're accessing the parsed JSON elements.

---

Below is a complete working example with a raw [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) as JSON input.

A few points:

- Use [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for `reader` to de-allocate memory appropriately at the end. In your code snippet, it's a memory leak.
- Read the documentation carefully! Accessing an element using a method or operator might return a [default value](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#a034eb7bf85a44fa759bdaa232788ca66) or an [exception](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#acb912f4ec40a25ea6eb387730885f3d9) so handle accordingly. For example, the JSON in `root` is an array so it should be accessed by index and then each index contains an object i.e. `root[0]["header"]`.

Example (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

int main()
{
    const std::string raw_json = R"json([{"header": "test" , "test2" : "test2"}])json";

    Json::CharReaderBuilder builder {};

    // Don't leak memory! Use std::unique_ptr!
    auto reader = std::unique_ptr<Json::CharReader>( builder.newCharReader() );

    Json::Value root {};
    std::string errors {};
    const auto is_parsed = reader->parse( raw_json.c_str(),
                                          raw_json.c_str() + raw_json.length(),
                                          &root,
                                          &errors );
    if ( !is_parsed )
    {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not parse! " << errors << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "Parsed JSON:\n" << root << "\n\n";

    try
    {
        std::cout << "header: " << root[0]["header"] << '\n';
        std::cout << "test2 : " << root[0]["test2"] << '\n';
    }
    catch ( const Json::Exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Parsed JSON:
[
    {
        "header" : "test",
        "test2" : "test2"
    }
]

header: "test"
test2 : "test2"
```